# Trigger nested resolvers with GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I think I'm missing something obvious in the way GraphQL resolvers work. This is a simplified example of my **schema** (a `Place` that can have `AdditionalInformation`):

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server';

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Place {
    name: String!
    additionalInformation: AdditionalInformation
  }

  type AdditionalInformation {
    foo: String
  }

  type Query {
    places: [Place]
  }
`;
```

And the associated **resolvers**:

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    places: () => {
        return [{name: 'Barcelona'}];
    }
  },
  AdditionalInformation: {
    foo: () => 'bar'
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({typeDefs, resolvers});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`API server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

When I execute a basic query:

```
{
  places {
    name,
    additionalInformation {
      foo
    }
  }
}
```

I always get `null` as the `additionalInformation`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "places": [
      {
        "name": "Barcelona",
        "additionalInformation": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It's my first GraphQL app, and I still don't get why the `AdditionalInformation` resolver is not automatically executed. Is there some way to let GraphQL know it has to fire it?

I've found this workaround but I find it a bit tricky:

```js
Place: {
  additionalInformation: () => { return {}; }
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume for a moment that `additionalInformation` was a Scalar, and not an Object type:

```
type Place {
  name: String!
  additionalInformation: String
}
```

The value returned by the `places` resolver is:

```
[{name: 'Barcelona'}]
```

If you were to make a similar query...

```
query {
  places {
    name
    additionalInformation
  }
}
```

What would you expect `additionalInformation` to be? It's value will be null because there is no `additionalInformation` property on the `Place` object returned by the `places` resolver.

Even if we make `additionalInformation` an Object type (like `AdditionalInformation`), the result is the same -- the `additionalInformation` field will resolve to null. That's because the default resolver (the one used when you don't specify a resolver function for a field) simply looks for a property with the same name as the field on the parent object. If it fails to find that property, it returns null.

You may have specified a resolver for a field on `AdditionalInformation` (`foo`), but this resolver is never fired because there's no need -- the whole `additionalInformation` field is null so all of the resolvers for any fields of the associated type are skipped.

To understand why this is a desirable behavior, imagine a different schema:

```
type Article {
  title: String!
  content: String!
  image: Image
}

type Image {
  url: String!
  copyright: String!
}

type Query {
  articles: [Article!]!
}
```

We have a database with an `articles` table and an `images` table as our data layer. An article may or may not have an image associated with it. My resolvers might look like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    articles: () => db.getArticlesWithImages()
  }
  Image: {
    copyright: (image) => `©${image.year} ${image.author}`
  }
}
```

Let's say our call `getArticlesWithImages` resolves to a single article with no image:

[{ title: 'Foo', content: 'All about foos' }]

As a consumer of the API, I request:

```
query {
  articles {
    title
    content
    image
  }
}
```

The `image` field is optional. If I get back an article object with a null `image` field, I understand there was no associated image in the db. As a front end client, I know not to render any image.

What would happen if GraphQL returned a value for the `image` regardless? Obviously, our resolver would break, since it would not be passed any kind of parent value. Moreover, however, as a consumer of the API, I would have to now parse the contents of `image` and somehow determine whether an image was in fact associated with the article and I should do something with it.

#### TLDR;

As you already suggested, the solution here is to specify a resolver for `additionalInfo`. You can also simply return that value in your `places` resolver, i.e.:

```
return [{name: 'Barcelona', additionalInfo: {}}]
```

In reality, if the shape of your schema aligns with the shape of your underlying data layer, it's unlikely you'll encounter this sort of issue when working with real data.

Comment: Understood. Thanks Daniel, very good explanation. That coupling between the domain model and the graphql schema is what I still find disturbing. In many cases there is no alignment (e.g. using a third-party library that uses a data model different than the one you want to expose in your GraphQL API) or you might want to rename fields, etc.

Comment: GraphQL's **default** resolver behavior makes some assumptions about the underlying data based on your schema. However, you're free to use whatever data you want and then transform it into the shape expected by your schema. So if your data source returns a flat Place object and you want to wrap some of those fields inside an `additionalInfo` object, have at it. You need to change field names from snake case to camel case, no problem. Just understand that by default GraphQL will not do it for you, you'll need to configure your resolvers accordingly.

Comment: There's often a balance to be struck between having a schema that is easily consumed by the client and one that can be resolved easily and efficiently. The more you need to manipulate and transform your data before returning it to the client, the more work you have to do and the less efficient the response is. But there's nothing inherently wrong with that if that's what's necessary. However, you should avoid designing a schema without considering the underlying data sources. That's just asking for headache.