# Combining GraphQL queries

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

I am building my first GraphQL based project so forgive me if this is a newbie question. I have arranged my queries and mutations in the following fashion:

```
├── graphql
│   ├── lessons
│   │   ├── logic.js
│   │   ├── query.js
│   │   ├── schema.js
│   │   └── types.js
│   ├── schema.js
│   └── users
│       ├── logic.js
│       ├── mutation.js
│       ├── query.js
│       ├── schema.js
│       └── types.js
```

This is my `users/query.js` file:

```
const graphql = require('graphql')
const types = require('./types.js')
const logic = require('./logic.js')

module.exports = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'UserQuery',
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: types.userType,
      args: {
        email: { type: new graphql.GraphQLNonNull(graphql.GraphQLString) }
      },
      resolve: (root, { email }, context) => logic.getUser(email, context)
    }
  }
})
```

In my `schema.js`, I have combined the queries of `users` and `lessons` as  per the following code:

```
module.exports = new graphql.GraphQLSchema({
  query: new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQuery',
    fields: {
      lessons: { type: require('./lessons/query.js') },
      users: { type: require('./users/query.js') }
    }
  })
})
```

Now the problem is, the following query:

```
{
 users {
    user(email: "a@.a") {
      name,
      purchases
    }
  }
}
```

is producing the following output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": null
  }
}
```

I am getting a `null` in place of a user record. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to provide a `resolve` function for the `users` field that returns an object, even if that object is empty. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216527/trigger-nested-resolvers-with-graphql/54219592#54219592) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: We should close or delete this question as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216527/trigger-nested-resolvers-with-graphql/54219592). While the OP of the other question was using Apollo, the problem and solution are still effectively the same.